# how to create an "offline" Java MimeMessage?

Tags: java, api, email, mime-types, jakarta-mail

Java [MimeMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) seems to require a Folder or Session for instantiation.  Is there a sort of "offline" variety which allows creation of the message first, and then later it can be turned into a full-fledged MIME message?  I'd like to stay within Java SE, but alternate API's would be ok if there's no such provision within SE.

If you create a message like so:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.example.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
```

can the message object get sent to other methods or classes?  Or will it just throw errors because the connection is bogus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a null session to the MimeMessage constructor but you'll have to manage your own session and transport later on.
See [Creating a email message in Java without a mail session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557332/creating-a-email-message-in-java-without-a-mail-session/17747165)