# Creating a email message in Java without a mail session

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I would like to create a utility method in my app that accepts an email message as an argument and knows how to send it.  This utility method would be responsible for knowing which SMTP server to use what credentials it should use to connect to it.

The problem that I'm running into with `javax.mail` is that the `javax.mail.Message` class and the `javax.mail.MimeMessage`class expect a `javax.mail.Session` object as an argument to the constructor.  So I can't have a method signature like

```
private static void sendMail(javax.mail.Message);
```

because my client classes won't be able to constuct the Message without all the details that I'm trying to abstract away.  They would have to know how to create a Session by connecting to the mail server.

Is there a way to create a Message without a session, or alternatively a class that encapsulates an email message that doesn't require a session?

Comment: Have you looked at the Apache Commons email package at all, or are you set on `javax.mail`?

Comment: I use Apache commons.  I'd be very happy with a solution that involves an open source package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Apache Commons Email](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email), any of the following code could be added to the sendMail method depending on where you want things set.

```
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    //email.setDebug(debugMode);
    email.setBounceAddress("bouce@domain.biz");
    email.setHostName("mySMTPHost");


    email.setFrom("myAddress@mydomain.com");
    email.addTo(emailAddress);
    email.addBcc("bccAddres");

    email.setSubject("Your Subject");
    email.setAuthentication("recipient@snailmail.org", "password");
    email.setSSL(true);
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setHtmlMsg(html);

public static void sendMail(org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail email)
{       
    email.send();
}
```

Comment: The libraries used in this example are from Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/. HTMLEmail is a class in the commons-email component of these libraries: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/

Answer (score 8):

The `MimeMessage` class will accept a null session.  If you create such a message, `Transport.send` may not be able to send your `MimeMessage` To workaround that you just have to manage your own session and transport objects then use the non-static `Transport.sendMessage` method.

```
public void forward(Session session, Message m) throws MessagingException {
    Address[] all = m.getAllRecipients();
    if (all == null) { //Don't pass null to sendMessage.
        all = new InternetAddress[0];
    }

    Transport t;
    try {
        // Session properties 'mail.transport.protocol.rfc822'
        // and 'mail.transport.protocol' can be used to change
        // between SMTP or SMTPS.

        if (all.length != 0) {
            t = session.getTransport(all[0]);
        } else {
            t = session.getTransport();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException punt) {
        try {
            t = session.getTransport("smtp"); //Just a guess.
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException fail) {
            if (fail.setNextException(punt)) {
                throw fail;
            } else {
                punt.setNextException(fail);
                throw punt;
            }
        }
    }

    m.saveChanges(); //Computes additional headers.

    t.connect("host", 25, "user", "pass"); //Or use one of the many other connect method overloads.
    try {
        t.sendMessage(m, all);
    } finally {
        try {
            t.close();
        } catch (MessagingException warning) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Spring framework / spring boot, you can inject a Spring JavaMailSenderImpl into your class, and do (obviously you would need the SMTP server properties injected into the mail sender too) :

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
```

You need to add the following dependency to your app for this to work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having each client create the message class on their own, have them get a message object from your utility class. Then the utility class can construct the message object with the desired session information.

Comment: Is there such a message utility object already built in some library, or is this something I would have to create?

Comment: I think you need to create it. Even spring uses the session object in JavaMailSenderImpl. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html

Comment: This answer is missing a code example or at least it should be pointed out clearly what utility class you are talking about (-1)

Comment: @BastianVoigt he is obviously talking about the utility class that the OP stated that he _would like to create_